# Selenium will not click, no name, id or class

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I would like selenium webdriver to click this link so I can proceed with my project. Here is my code. No errors, but it does not click the link.

```
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/span/  
a[7]')
x.click()
```

Here is the HTML

```
<tr>
  <td width="100%">
    <span style="white-space: nowrap">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://staffmate.com/imagessm/OEA_sm_lt.gif" border="0" width="125" height="36">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://staffmate.com/imagessm/OPOS_sm_lt.gif" border="0" width="125" height="36">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://staffmate.com/imagessm/OCTR_sm_lt.gif" border="0" width="125" height="36">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://staffmate.com/imagessm/OCL_sm_lt.gif" border="0" width="125" height="36">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://staffmate.com/imagessm/OVEN_sm_lt.gif" border="0" width="125" height="36">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://staffmate.com/imagessm/OEV_sm_dk.gif" border="0" width="125" height="36">
      </a>
      <a href="eprintreports.php?eSessID=199495633810875522501415473608154261624185901388039708769020171218111124">
        <img src="https://staffmate.com/imagessm/PREP_sm_lt.gif" border="0" width="125" height="36">
      </a>
      </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to click the 7th link. I copied the xpath straight from Chrome's inspection tool. I'm aware that an absolute xpath is unreliable but what else am I to use when there are no class names, id's or names? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: I've added the URL

Comment: The URL still doesn’t seem to be in the description, could you add it please so we can help further

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the `<a>` tag may not fetch you desired output. You need to go deeper till the `<img>` tag and invoke `click()` as follows :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td/span//a/img[contains(@src,'https://staffmate.com/imagessm/PREP_sm_lt.gif')]").click()
```

> **Note** : We could have done away with a shorter value for `src` attribute as **`PREP`** but ideally we should consider the full `value` of the attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately this causes an error: no such element. This is the same error as when I try to find_element_by_link_text. The link is not clickable when I view the source through my IDE: print(driver.page_source). Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Cameron Can you elaborate what do mean by link is not clickable. Please update the question with a bit of more outerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following xpath:

```
"//a[contains(@src, 'PREP')]"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately this causes an error: no such element. This is the same error as when I try to find_element_by_link_text. The link is not clickable when I view the source through my IDE: print(driver.page_source). Could this be the problem?